# SSIS Failed to retrieve long data for column varchar(max)

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I want build a package that imports excel rows to an SQL server table, the problem is that sometimes there is an error that fails the package process.

> [Excel Source [1]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB
>   error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E21. [Excel Source [1]] Error:
>   Failed to retrieve long data for column "RECOMENDACION". [Excel Source
>   [1]] Error: There was an error with output "Excel Source Output" (9)
>   on component "Excel Source" (1). The column status returned was:
>   "DBSTATUS_UNAVAILABLE".

as you can see, there is something wrong with the column "RECOMENDACION".

Note: the error is in Excel Source task.

Comment: The problem seems to be related to the interpretation of the column type by the ace driver. This might help you : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6496b806-c0d9-4ab7-b309-aa34550aaa1d/ole-db-connection-error-failed-to-retrieve-long-data-for-column

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Apparently the MS Jet Database Engine checks the first 8 rows of a column to try and guess what the data type of the column is (regardless of what type you specify).

Mine was fixed when I changed the value of the registry key TypeGuessRows from 8 to 0.
This key is going to be in either of these locations:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Excel

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE -> SOFTWARE -> Wow6432Node -> Microsoft -> Jet -> 4.0 ->Engines -> Excel

Answer (score 0):

Decreasing the `DefaultBufferMaxRows` helped in my case.

It might be luck, but it helped.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was creating a new oledb source. I was reusing the existing oledb source for my new query. Changing it solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I've just had the problem, and it turned out to be a missing
**"C:\SSISTempStoragePath"** 
directory. 
Such a simple problem with a very cryptic error message. SSIS will create a file in this directory for each column and each row in the source. Beware of AntiVirus wanting to scan all these files.
The files are named "DTB{>a GUID here<}.tmp", and are all zero (0) bytes long.